# Need to add delay to the model popup ( Pure JS )

Tags: javascript, html

How to add delay to the popup...
I Tryed couple of silution but didnt work,
What's the trick to achieve delay to the below model.

Thanks in advance

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

```css
.show-modal {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<button class="trigger">Click the modal!</button>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close-button">×</span>
        <h1>Hello, I am a modal!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think adding a timeout function will work fine...check settimeout in js

Comment: What you mean by a delay? a time delay before closing/opening the modal ? you cans use : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/setTimeout in your toggleModal function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [setTimeout method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to add delay

It takes a method and a delay in millisecond as `setTimeout(functionRef, delay)`.

---

Here is an exmaple for delaying the modal by 1s

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {

  setTimeout(() => {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
  }, 1000)
    
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

```css
.modal {
  opacity: 0
}

.show-modal {
    opacity: 1!important;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<button class="trigger">Click the modal!</button>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close-button">×</span>
        <h1>Hello, I am a modal!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use css **transition-delay** property.

Here is the  [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay)

Answer (score 0):

delays are achive with timeout

```
function toggleModalDelayed() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }, milliseconds)
}
```